# Compass CSS Online Compiling using PHP

Tags: compilation, ssh, terminal, compass-sass

I got a hosting server which allows me SSH connection and I am successfully managed to install  Compass on it. I have an application which requires me to compile Compass CSS to W3C CSS on the go. I am using PHP server side language and wants to compile compass files as the user requests it.

I know how to do that but the question is about performance and how can I handle concurrent user requests of compiling through a single SSH connection. Assuming the user should receive the compiled CSS quickly, what are my options to handle this type of thing?

I would like to add more detail. I want my user to upload their SCSS files to my server and then compile it into normal CSS at the server, once compiled, the file will be sent to the user again for the download. It would seem user seamless as they just uploaded and then downloaded the file. But behind the scene compilation is occurred. I can do that this way...

1. User uploads file (send POST request)
2. I process the request by getting file, reading contents, writing to scss file.
3. I connected to server terminal using SSH and compiled this file using **compass compile** and then send compiled file back to the user as request (POST) response.

There would be huge SSH connections and my server would be exhausted. How can I optimize having just single SSH connection and that connection processing all requests coming to it?

Answer (score 0):

"wants to compile compass files as the user requests it" this is not the intended use of compass or sass they are meant to be compiled to static files and served as static assets. If you still want to go down this road take a look into the `sass --compass` command and pipe the output to the used via php. We get this question a lot and my only real answer is you may need to build a worker queue system if compile times are too long when serving on demand.